# Function file_exists always return false

Tags: php

I always get false when calling a function file_exists.
I can get the full path of a file using `readlink -f test.txt`.
And then when I do `file_exists('/home/user/projects/test_project/test.txt')`, I'm getting false. Why?

I was thinking maybe something with the file permissions. But the chmod or chown didn't help me.
Moving the file to the folder `file_exists('/home/user/test.txt')` didn't help me too.

PHP8.0

Comment: Note: The results of this function are cached. See [clearstatcache()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php) for more details.

Comment: When you do readlink -f text.txt, you are acccessing the file with shell user rights, for example if you logged in as root. But when do file_exists() you are accessing the file with web user rights, as on debian, you are www-data user. So you can try this: chown www-data test.txt, then again call file_exists().

Comment: pls do some research, there are many posts about this behaviour

Comment: File exists works perfectly on PHP 8.0 and 8.0.2. First you have to determine your project root folder. You can use __DIR__ to get your current directory and then append the remaining path to the __DIR__ constant and then echo it out. $x =  file_exists($path."/practice/json.php");
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($x);
echo "</pre>"; You will get true if the file exists or false if it does not exist

Answer (score 1):

file_exists uses the rights of the running process, so the process must have access to the folder.
i believe this is a system restriction, and not a php issue.
can you use file_exists on the script running? like an file_exists("./index.php");